# How can i access script from Electron/React App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

My Folder structure:

```
├── client
│   ├── public
│        └── electron.js
│   ├── src
│        └── App.tsx
├── script
│   ├── main.js
```

App.tsx:

```
const handleStart = () => {
    const pathScript = path.join(__dirname, '../../script/main.js');
    console.log(pathScript);
    spawn(`node ${pathScript}`);
  };
```

I just want my react app(created with CRA) to access the script and spawn it but it gives this error:
[image]

How can i access script? should i look at something like [lerna](https://lerna.js.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to spawn a new child process, you have to do it from the electron side (main process) not from the react side (renderer process).
Remember the renderer process is simply a browser executing your react code(similar to a website), and websites can't just spawn processes on your computer or visiting websites would be a lot more dangerous.
So move the spawn part to the main electron js file (or any other file that it imports)